# Why does Rider dislike prefixing variable names with `test` in C#?

Tags: c#, rider

Our existing project has a number of variable names relating to test scenarios that have `test` as the beginning of their name. JetBrains Rider highlights all of these variables with the issue:

> Name 'testScenarioResults' does not match rule 'Local variables'. Suggested name is 'scenarioResults'.

The [Rider documentation on this analysis result](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/InconsistentNaming.html) suggests [adjusting the configured naming style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html) in the IDE, which appears to relate only to capitalization (unless the style rules are more complex than their name suggests). Further, I have been unable to find any sources explaining why `test` specifically goes against convention.

It looks like unchecking "use auto-detected values" in the naming style settings prevents this behavior from occurring, but I do not understand why.

Naming-related editorconfig values are as follows:

```
# Style Definitions
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization             = pascal_case

# Use PascalCase for constant fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.symbols  = constant_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_should_be_pascal_case.style    = pascal_case_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_kinds            = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_accessibilities  = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.required_modifiers          = const
```

Where could this rule be coming from and how can I disable it without crippling the rest of the naming style rules?

Comment: seems unrelated to c#

Comment: Probably word `test` does not add meaning to the variable name? Try to add `hi` instead of `test`

Comment: Does the message change based on what you are assigning to the variable or its type? What is the type of the variable?

Comment: @Rafael it does not seem to complain with `hi`.

Comment: @julealgon type doesn't seem to have any impact. There are variables of type `IOptions` and `List` both affected. It also complains regardless of whether it's a local variable or a parameter.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html

Comment: Sounds like your `.editorconfig` settings for C# style: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules

Comment: @Dai That's a reasonable suggestion. I looked through the editorconfig and didn't find anything relevant. Added the related block to my question for others to see.

Comment: Do you have any other `.editorconfig` files _anywhere_ going all the way back up to your root `C:\` directory? Doesn't Rider's Error List window show you the origin of every message?

Comment: No additional editorconfig files in the path (also this is a Mac, but I get the idea). Rider doesn't appear to show the origin of the errors.